# Add hour and minutes to a string with hh:mm?

Tags: javascript

I have a string containing `13:00` , i have an duration of `90` for example and i have to convert the duration to `hh:mm` which i made it. Now i have a string with `1:30`. How can i add this `1:30` string to the other `13:00` string so i can compare it with another strings? This is how i conver the duration

```
var bookH = Math.floor(data[0]['Duration'] / 60);
    var bookM = data[0]['Duration'] % 60;
    var bookingDurationToHour = bookH + ':' + bookM;
```

There is momentjs in the project but i still do not know how can i do that.

Comment: Possibly consider using [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for these kind of operations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution with plain javascript.

```
var time = "13:00";
var totalInMinutes = (parseInt(time.split(":")[0]) * 60) + parseInt(time.split(":")[1]);

var otherMinutes = 90;

var grandTotal = otherMinutes + totalInMinutes;

//Now using your own code

var bookH = Math.floor(grandTotal / 60);
var bookM = grandTotal % 60;
var bookingDurationToHour = bookH + ':' + bookM;

alert(bookingDurationToHour);
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/V7AVdRZ15Ra8omi1J4hl?p=preview)

Answer (score 3):

I've used [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) before as vanilla JS with dates can be a bit difficult

First you want to put your time into a date time object

```
var myDate = Date.parse("2017-05-25 " + time);
```

Then you can add your time using the Datejs library:

```
myDate = myDate.addMinutes(90);
```

Then toString your new date as a time:

```
var newTime = myDate.toString("HH:MM");
```